# Importing .cix NumPy API catalog in Komodo Edit

Tags: python, numpy, komodoedit, code-intelligence

I've generated a numpy.cix file by following the instructions given here: http://community.activestate.com/faq/generate-python-api-catalog

via the command

```
python gencix.py --onefile=numpy.cix --name="NumPy" --description="Python NumPy module" numpy
```

Unfortunately, after importing the numpy.cix API catalog into Komodo Edit 8.5.3, a simple numpy.empty command is not found in the auto-completion (e.g. after typing `s=numpy.e`)

Am I misunderstanding something about the code completion, is it a bug of the cix-generating program python_gencix or one of Komodo Edit?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Search for the location of other cix files:

```
Komodo stores preferences, macros, templates, keybinding schemes and other settings in a user-specific directory called the user data directory. The name and location of this directory varies depending on the operating system and Komodo version:

Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 or newer
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\ActiveState\Komodo[IDE|Edit]\

Windows XP or older
C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\ActiveState\Komodo[IDE|Edit]\

Linux
/home//.komodo[ide|edit]/

Mac OS X
/Users//Library/Application Support/Komodo[IDE|Edit]/
```

- For example:

  ```
  KomodoEdit\8.0\apicatalogs\
  ```
- Restart Komodo

**References**

- [Komodo Profile Structure](http://community.activestate.com/faq/komodo-profile-structure)
- [Komodo Source: codeintel2 catalogs](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/tree/master/src/codeintel/lib/codeintel2/catalogs)